# ¿Como buscar directorios con Bash?

Tags: bash, condiciones, while, echo

una consulta quisiera buscar si existe un directorio que tiene este formato directorio-1.1.1, lo hice así:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d "dierectorio-[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]" ]
   then
      echo "El directorio existe, se procederá a borrar"
      rm -rf directorio-[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]
   else 
      echo OK
fi
```

El problema es que no funciona, y también deseo que lo elimine exceptuando uno en particular por ejemplo `directorio-1.0.2`

Comment: Según de eso https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147681/how-to-pass-a-regex-when-finding-a-directory-path-in-bash (en inglés) no es fácil, pero hay respuestas

Comment: @Duston gracias por ese aporte en realidad me dió una gran idea de como hacerlo

Comment: No tendrás un tipo en `dierectorio`. Es decir, `dierectorio` cuando debería de ser `directorio`.

Comment: Además, creo que al final tiene dos `[0-9][0-9]` lo cual me parece que implica que el directorio tendrá que tener necesariamente una terminación de dos números.

Answer (score 2):

Es bastante fácil si puedes usar `bash` y expresiones regulares:

```
#!/bin/bash
guardar='directorio-1.0.2'
regex='^directorio-[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*/'

## itera sobre todos los directorios
for dir in */; do
  ## Mira si este cumple las condiciones
  if [[ $dir =~ $regex ]]; then
    ## Es lo que queremos guardar?
    if  [ "$dir" = "$guardar"/ ]; then
      echo "'$guardar' encontrado, no se procederá a borrar"
    else
         echo "El directorio '$dir' existe, se procederá a borrar"
         rm -r -- "$dir"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Lo prové en una carpeta con varios directorios y un fichero:

```
$ ls -F
directorio-100.1.1/  directorio-1.1.1/  directorio-1.1.2.123.2/    directorio.5.6.7
directorio-1.0.2/    directorio-1.1.2/  directorio-3211.33211.10/  directorio-malo/
```

Después del script:

```
$ foo.sh
El directorio 'directorio-100.1.1/' existe, se procederá a borrar
'directorio-1.0.2' encontrado, no se procederá a borrar
El directorio 'directorio-1.1.1/' existe, se procederá a borrar
El directorio 'directorio-1.1.2/' existe, se procederá a borrar
El directorio 'directorio-3211.33211.10/' existe, se procederá a borrar

$ ls -F
directorio-1.0.2/  directorio-1.1.2.123.2/  directorio.5.6.7  directorio-malo/
```

Answer (score 1):

Te serviría utilizar la utilidad `find` con el flag `-regex` en lugar de `bash`?:

```
$ find /tmp/dirs -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*directorio-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
/tmp/dirs/directorio-1.1.1
/tmp/dirs/directorio-1.1.2
```